# How can I add for loop code into single line to speed up execution time?

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I want to add for loop code in single line so I can speed up execution time.

Python code:

```
> criteria_df = pd.read_csv(cfpath)
> 
> for type in data.type:
> 
>       criteria_df.drop(criteria_df.index[criteria_df['question'] == type], inplace=True)   
> 
>       criteria_df.to_csv(cfpath)       
> 
>       trials_df, sum_trails = determine_trial_eligibility(trials, criteria_df)
```

Comment: Given the contents of the loop (including writing to the file system), I doubt that the `for` loop overhead is a performance bottleneck in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure that the datatype of the `question` column is `category`. This will speed up the comparison.
- saving the file in each iteration is where the main execution time is happening. I don't think this can be vectorized if you save it to a file.
- use `to_pickle` as it is faster than `to_csv`
- after the loop then you can convert the pickle to csv